# How to save png image in mongodb with angularjs and deployd

Tags: angularjs, image, mongodb, deployd

I am working on an app where I need to retrieve images from URLS (for example http://foo.com/bar.png) and save them in mongodb. The app is built using angularjs and uses deployd for the API stuff. Here is the config.js file for the image collection:

```
{
    "type": "Collection",
    "properties": {
        "image": {
            "name": "image",
            "type": "image/png",
            "typeLabel": "image/png",
            "required": true,
            "id": "image",
            "order": 0
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried searching but I was unable to find anything for images and deployd. I just need a simple way to retrieve images from URLs, save them in mongodb and then render them later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no column type `image/png` AFAIK. We can use string instead of it. Why not inserting the image as [data uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs)?

```
{
    "type": "Collection",
    "properties": {
        "image": {
            "name": "image",
            "type": "string",
            "typeLabel": "string",
            "required": true,
            "id": "image",
            "order": 0
        }
    }
}
```